# Meteor: Can't send emails: SenderError: Mail from command failed - 501 Syntax error

Tags: meteor, mailgun

I have asked this question on official meteor forum, but it didn't get any attention. I have deployed my meteor app via meteor deploy to the standard meteor hosting(appXX.meteor.com); I'd like to test sending emails from server, however when I try, I get this error:

```
SenderError: Mail from command failed - 501 Syntax
error
```

It's true, that I didn't setup a mailgun account, but my understanding is, that meteor takes care of that... when I debug my MAIL_URL env variable it's something like this:

```
smtp://postmaster%40appXXXXXX.mailgun.org:password@smtp.mailgun.org:587
```

My email sending code, in coffeescript looks like this:

```
Email.send "postmaster@appXXXXXX.mailgun.org", "testemail@testemail.com", 
"Test subject", "Test email body"
```

To be more specific, the error message is not a mistake in my code(most likely, although I don't want to rule out that option, but I believe, my code really is ok), I think it's just a question of configuration of some account or whatever... I really don't know.

I'm probably missing something obvious. Can anybody help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Email.send`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email_send) does not take a list of parameters, it takes a single `options` argument containing the mail sending operation configuration :

```
Email.send
  from: "postmaster@appXXXXXX.mailgun.org"
  to: "testemail@testemail.com"
  subject: "Test subject"
  text: "Test email body"
```

Comment: thank you, you're absolutely right, I knew I missed something obvious. Right into my face, saying how much I believe my code is correct -.-'

Answer (score 1):

The error `Mail from command failed - 501 Syntax error` is also thrown when the `from` field is not set:

```
Email.send({  // <-- throws 'Mail from command failed - 501 Syntax error'
  to: "testemail@testemail.com",
  subject: "Test subject",
  text: "Test email body",
});
```

Fix:

```
Email.send({  // <-- runs OK
  from: "postmaster@appXXXXXX.mailgun.org"
  to: "testemail@testemail.com",
  subject: "Test subject",
  text: "Test email body",
});
```